# Problem with algorithm in Python Code - Unpacking

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using the Floyd Warshall algorithm to find and register the shortest path between two pairs. I need to use a matrix (n x n), and then process it in the algorithm. I'm using the code below, but I keep getting an unpacking error, and it seems that it's reading the matrix as (n x n-1), and not (n x n).

The part in bold is where the unpacking error is giving

"File "C:\Users\marcelo.novaes\Desktop\floydwarshall\floydwarshall_run.py", line 19, in floyd_warshall
for u, v, w in edge:
File "C:\Users\marcelo.novaes\Desktop\floydwarshall\floydwarshall_run.py", line 39, in 
floyd_warshall(len(edge)-1, edge)"

```
#import the vertices/distance matrix
import numpy as np

edge = np.loadtxt('text1.txt', usecols=range(106))
n = len(edge)

#Floyd Warshall Algorithm

from math import inf
from itertools import product


def floyd_warshall(n, edge):
    rn = range(n)
    dist = [[inf] * n for i in rn]
    nxt = [[0] * n for i in rn]
    for i in rn:
        dist[i][i] = 0
    **for u, v, w in edge:
        dist[u - 1][v - 1] = w
        nxt[u - 1][v - 1] = v - 1
    for k, i, j in product(rn, repeat=3):
        sum_ik_kj = dist[i][k] + dist[k][j]
        if dist[i][j] > sum_ik_kj:
            dist[i][j] = sum_ik_kj
            nxt[i][j] = nxt[i][k]**
    print("    pair        dist     path")
    for i, j in product(rn, repeat=2):
        if i != j:
            path = [i]
            while path[-1] != j:
                path.append(nxt[path[-1]][j])
            print("%3d → %3d  %4d       %s"
                  % (i + 1, j + 1, dist[i][j],
                     ' → '.join(str(p + 1) for p in path)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
   floyd_warshall(len(edge)-1, edge)
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Double check your data. You haven't posted the full error, but if you're getting an unpacking error, `edge` doesn't (always) contain iterables with exactly three elements.

Comment: Try `print([len(list(sub)) for sub in edge if len(list(sub)) != 3])` as a quick diagnostic. What does that print?

Comment: Looks like `edge` (from `loadtxt`) will be a `(n,106) array of floats.  `for ... in edge` will get one row, but `u,v,w in edge` will work only if that row has exactly 3 elements.  `unpacking` like that is quite picky about dimensions.

Comment: @Carcigenicate it prints an array of the number 106 a bunch of times.

Comment: @mcnovaes That means that your data isn't made up of rows of 3, which `for u, v, w in edge:` is expecting. You might need to parse the data first if it's strings.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks! the matrix is supposed to be 106 x 106, and the algorithm should run for those many variables. Maybe the example/source I used was only for a 3 x 3 matrix. Looking at other options. Thanks guys.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks mate. Sorry for the stupid question, but how would that work? I'm thinking I need a different code base structure.